# How to prove Slutsky matrix's symmetry for L=2

Tags: microeconomics, slutsky-equation

I don't understand how to prove slutsky matrix is symmetric for L=2
$$\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial p_2}+\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial w}\cdot x_2= \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial p_1}+\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial w}\cdot x_1$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $c(p, u)$ be the expenditure function. The Hicksian demand for good $j$ is the derivative of $c$ with respect to $p_j$.
$$
\frac{\partial c(p,u)}{\partial p_j} = h_j(p,u).
$$
From this, it follows (by Young's theorem) that:
$$
\frac{\partial h_j(p,u)}{\partial p_i} = \frac{\partial^2 c(p,u)}{\partial p_j \partial p_i} = \frac{\partial^2 c(p,u)}{\partial p_i \partial p_j} = \frac{\partial h_i(p,u)}{\partial p_j},
$$
So the Hicksian cross price effects are symmetric. Using the Slutsky equation, we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial x_i(p,m)}{\partial p_j} + \frac{\partial x_i(p,m)}{\partial m} x_i(p,m),\\
&= \frac{\partial h_i(p,u)}{\partial p_j},\\
&= \frac{\partial h_j(p,u)}{\partial p_i},\\
&= \frac{\partial x_j(p,m)}{\partial p_i} + \frac{\partial x_j(p,m)}{\partial m} x_j(p,m).
\end{align*}
$$